# Kafka writing in disk logs time

Tags: apache-kafka

Running some perf test on Kafka, we are having bad latency in the producer.
Checking the kafka broker logs I can see this log

[Topic]  Wrote producer snapshot at offset 331258 with 62 producer ids in 860 ms. (kafka.utils.Logging)

I dont know if this is the time that it takes to write in disk or replicas before ack to the producer(ack=all) but those 800ms it seems a lot to me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This needs a detailed analysis. Here are few things that you can do:

1. Monitor kafka broker/producer resources like CPU/Memory to see if any particular resource is reaching near 100% usage.
2. If kafka broker resource is saturating, then for your load you might need to provide more resources to your kafka broker. Same logic is applicable on your kafka producer.
3. If resources are not saturating, you would need to play around with your kafka producer configuration. Calculate rough throughput of your kafka producers (in messages/sec as well as bytes/sec). Check kafka producer config defaults to see if you can find a probable cause. There are a lot of producer configs like: `batch.size`, `buffer.memory`, `linger.ms`, `max.request.size` etc any of which might be the reason for your producer to not perform in an optimum way.

Comment: The latency happens in the brokers not in the producer

Comment: Did you try monitoring the broker resources to find possible reasons?

Comment: yes Is the log that I refer in the question :)

Comment: no resources struggling like cpu, ram or disk